# ROS Installation Error : ARCH LINUX

Tags: ros, python, linux

[image]So I had this old lappy on which I used to play with ROS a lot then it got broken so I bought a new one and installed the same distro as that of old one i.e. arch linux. Now when I am installing the ROS via AUR I get this build error please help me fix this.

```
Scanning dependencies of target libqt_gui_cpp_sip
[ 85%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/jade/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 50, in <module>
    config = Configuration()
 File "/opt/ros/jade/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 19, in __init__
    ['qmake', '-query'], env=env, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:90: sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:375: src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
```

Comment: Move to Stack Overflow...

Comment: This looks quite similar to this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593473/problems-during-compilation-of-ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp-in-arch-linux-arm), where the user was missing qt5-base

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593473/problems-during-compilation-of-ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp-in-arch-linux-arm), where the user was missing qt5-base.

(added this as an answer to make the community bot happy)